# Combining classification models for fraud detection

Tags: classification, ensemble-learning, fraud-detection

i have a classification problem : fraud / non fraud. My classes are inbalanced ( 0.8% fraud rows ).

I first split my data in train and test sets.

Let's say I have 10 fraud and 100 non fraud rows in a train set.
What I want to do using python ( and sklearn package) is the following :

- put in front of my 10 fraud rows , 10 non fraud rows
- fit a model mdl_01 ( i think of xgboost rigth now but it could be anything else ... later studies will help decide )
- put in front of my 10 fraud rows, 10 other non fraud rows
- fit a model mdl_02
  ...
- put in front of my 10 fraud rows, 10 other non fraud rows
- fit a model mdl_10

So I have a bunch MDL := ( mdl_01 , ... , mdl_10 ) of models fitted on all the fraud rows available on the train set and on dedicated subset of non fraud rows available in the train set.

I want to then use MDL on the entire train set so that if more models predict a row as fraud then it is classified as such.

Finally, I want to make prediction on my test set to see how well it performs.

My questions are :

Is it a proper way to do what i describe?

How can I store each model mdl_ to later on combine them ( voting step ) ?

How can I combine each model mdl_ to have one final unique classification ?

A few code snipets would help. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you train on whole data?

Comment: I feel like having a strong inbalanced target variable could be a problem. My way to deal with that is to put in front of my fraud rows an equal number of non fraud rows and have a model fitted on that data subset. By iterating and afterwhile voting i think ( and hope ) i could get pretty good results. I have to admit i have no theorical demonstration of my guess.

Comment: It seems like [***https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23586/sklearn-aggregating-multiple-fitted-models-into-a-single-model-binary-classifi***](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23586/sklearn-aggregating-multiple-fitted-models-into-a-single-model-binary-classifi) is a good answer to my question.